# How to enable/disable fragment button, within main activity in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, button, android-activity, fragment, isenabled

There are several answers to questions similar to this one, but none in Kotlin.

I have a main activity with a button and two fragments. In the first fragment there is a navigation button that launches the second fragment when clicked.

What I want to do is to be able to enable/disable the navigation button from the main activity.

Is it possible at all?

Here is the main activity layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/demo_nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="409dp"
        android:layout_height="729dp"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/navigation_graph" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/activateButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="92dp"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

First fragment layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".FirstFragment">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/userText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="164dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="text"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/navButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Navigate"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="373dp" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

and Second fragment layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/constraintLayout2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".SecondFragment" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/argText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

And here is the main activity code:

```
package com.ebookfrenzy.navigationdemo

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.net.Uri
import com.ebookfrenzy.navigationdemo.databinding.ActivityMainBinding

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(),
    SecondFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener {
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
        listenerSetup()
    }

    override fun onFragmentInteraction(uri: Uri) {
    }

    private fun listenerSetup() {

        binding.activateButton.setOnClickListener{

            // here I want to change the isEnabled property of the fragment button navButton
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set a boolean value to the button in the activity, like enable/disable, then save its value when you click button, true or false.
Since you are using Navigation, you can pass the boolean value as arguments to the first fragment, like this

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/firstFragment"
    android:name="com.example.FirstFragment"
    android:label="First Fragment">
    <argument
        android:name="isClicked"
        app:argType="boolean" />
</fragment>
```

So when you click button in the activity, you can save it to the boolean variable and then pass its last value to the first fragment.

Comment: thanks for the tip. I tried this. But the only thing I manage is to retrieve the parameter once at the start of the fragment activity (override fun onStart). There must be some way to update the parameter eah time you press the button. do you know how ?

Comment: So you need this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69126047/change-activitys-button-state-from-fragment
Define an interface and implement this interface in your activity, then in your fragment button click, call and set its value. @SimonW

Comment: ok. But what i want is just the opposite to what they describe in the link : I want to change the status of a fragment button from the main activity, not the opposite. So I tried it nevertheless. I defined the interface, made the fragment (not the Activity) implement it and I tried to call the function in the Activity button listener.     private fun listenerSetup() {
        binding.activateButton.setOnClickListener {
            (activity as? ButtonStateManager)?.setEnabled(true)
        } The fact is 'activity' is not recognized by the IDE.